# Georeferencing JPSS-1/NOAA-20 L2 data (VJ109_NRT) with Python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, modis, hdf, noaa

I'm new to satellite image processing. I am working with a collection of VJ109_NRT - JPPS1 images. It is a L2 VIIRS product. They come with an extension .nc.
I have read the proposed documentation (same for NPP and JPSS-1 products [*link*](https://viirsland.gsfc.nasa.gov/PDF/VIIRS_Surf_Refl_UserGuide_v2.0.pdf)) and several articles trying to georeference data correctly. The data is supplied with coordinates that are explicitly specified in EPSG:4326 (as example GRingLatitude=-3.70198226, 0.3605142236, -20.11667824, -24.55309677). However, the [guide](https://viirsland.gsfc.nasa.gov/PDF/VIIRS_Surf_Refl_UserGuide_v2.0.pdf) mentions that a sinusoidal coordinate system is used for georeferencing. So, I`m using point from boundary box (contained in metadata as GRingLatitude/GRingLongitude). My algorithm is following: I download the images -> get them from geotiff files -> translate the coordinates of the boundaryBox points into a sinusoidal coordinate system -> reproject the image in a sinusoidal system by points -> translate to EPSG:4326? If I use this algorithm, then the position of the objects in the images is very different from the real one. The same happens if I immediately reference to EPSG:4326 using a thin plate spline (TPS).

I use Python GDAL and it is desirable for me to find a solution using this technology. And I also use QGIS to check results (I've implemented above algorithm with QGIS but I've tried in python too and the results are the same).

So I've tried to use some know solutions such as GDAL warp function. But it returns nothing (None). My code and output is below.

```
from osgeo import gdal

# Image from VJ109 collection - JPPS1 (near real time)
filename = 'VJ109_NRT.A2023318.0418.002.2023318063700.hdf'

data = gdal.Open(filename)

# retrieve M3 band
subdataset = gdal.Open(data.GetSubDatasets()[5][0])

print("Driver short name:", subdataset.GetDriver().ShortName)
print("Driver long name:", subdataset.GetDriver().LongName)
print("Raster size:", subdataset.RasterXSize, "x", subdataset.RasterYSize)
print("Number of bands:", subdataset.RasterCount)
print("Projection:", subdataset.GetProjection())
print("Geo transform:", subdataset.GetGeoTransform())
print("GCP:", subdataset.GetGCPs())

gdal_output_name = "VJ109_test.tif"

dst_ds = gdal.Warp(gdal_output_name, subdataset, tps=True)

print(type(dst_ds)) # retruns None -- nothing is warping

print("Ok")
gdalData = None
dst_ds = None
```

Output:

```
Driver short name: HDF4Image
Driver long name: HDF4 Dataset
Raster size: 3200 x 3232
Number of bands: 1
Projection: 
Geo transform: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
GCP: ()
<class 'NoneType'>
Ok
```

Also I used QGIS to make template. I tried different ways (in different coordinate systems) but objects in images are still not on their places.
Example (by the algorithm above): Red dots are coordinates I've got from GRingLatitude/Longitude. The image is translated from sinusoidal to EPSG:4326 after referncing. As you can see, Australia shifted away. I've also fixed a bow-tie effect with my python code, but this is not the subject of question.
[image: Example of shifting after reprojecting in QGIS]

**So, the question is: what is the propper way to georeference JPSS-1 L2 data?**
If I understood everything correctly, then the method for PS1 should be the same as for other MODIS products (NPP, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Any Question with a bullet list of questions is in grave danger of being closed for lack of *focus*. Please [Edit] the Question.